Potential function of a flow around a stagnation point
Following the Steve Brunton lecture about the potential flow. It is possible de find the potential function by solving the Laplace's equation. In his first example (the same as the following picture) it seems impossible to find the potential functions by solving the Laplace equation in cartesian coordinates.
The solution for the Laplace's equation $\Delta \phi = 0 $ in 2d is
$$\phi = \sum_m (A_m e^{mx} + B_m e^{-mx}) (C_m sin(my) + D_m cos (my))
$$
From the scheme, far from the stagnation point at $x=0$ the velocity must be constant in $-y$ direction.
Hence, the velocity could be something like $\vec{u} = -u_0 \hat{y}$ far from the stagnation point.
Also, knowing th at $$\vec{u} = \nabla \phi $$
$$\phi = -u_0 y$$ far from the stagnation point.
Hence, $$\sum_m (A_m e^{mx} + B_m e^{-mx}) (C_m sin(my) + D_m cos (my)) = -u_0 y$$ far from the stagnation point.
For my understanding, the equality above seems impossible, why?
Edit: From what I saw from multiple examples, the stream function should be in the form of $\Psi = Axy$, which imply a potential flow in the form of $\phi = A(x^2 - y^2)$. However, this function doesn't agree with my solution for the Laplace's equation.

